# First data augmentation or dataset splitting?

Tags: keras

I want to create a CNN binary classifier to identify satellite images. I have about 13000 pics. I took 8000 pics and divided into two groups: one where the object appears and the other group. From 8000 pics only 85 photos had the element which I am searching. Should I now rotate, scale etc these 85 photos to get like 400 and then divide both groups into train, valid and test datasets?

Comment: Why do you only select 8000 and not all? It won't help your training if one class is very rare. So it makes sense to use some augmentation and then divide in batches. You can also selectively pick your training data with an eye to balance the object and non-object images; and then augment them further.

Comment: @Anakin It took really long to analyze these 8000 pics and I don't have that much time. I will rotate every image 10 times to get some bigger sample. Then I will divide it into 3 groups.

Answer (score 0):

85 images seem very little for training a model. But I would definitely first split them into train, val and test, because you want to ensure that these sets are as different as possible. If you first apply data augmentation and then split into sets, you need watch out that all variations of one image end up in the same set. First splitting and then augmenting your data seems like the safer way to go.

Comment: I just did the augmentation few moments ago :(. Its no problem to split it right because I have 11 rotated pics and 1 original so I will split by the multiplication of 12.

Comment: Yes you can do that, just watch out that the rotations of one image are all in one subset. I don't know what your learning task is, but consider also other augmentation techniques like saturation and brightness manipulation, mirroring or random crop.

Comment: I managed to put the rotated samples of one picture in the same subset. I managed to get 80% accuracy but when I predicted some pictures the ones with a probability of 99% didn't have the searched object :(. I got 2112 images as training set and 1056 images each in test and validation set.

Comment: Why are your validation and test sets so big? I would use 80% for train, 10% for validation and 10% for testing. How did you define accuracy? Did you try other data augmentation techniques? What kind of model do you use?

Comment: I copied the proportions from Deep Learning in R. I used acc in metrics while compiling the model. I tried width_shift_range, height_shift_range, shear_range, zoom_range. Its a CNN model with a binary_crossentropy loss function.

Comment: Basically I want to get an information from the model if the object appears in the image.

Comment: It's hard to say anything about your model with having so little information, buz I suggest you do sanity checks first. Try starting off with a small subset and see if your model can get to 100% accuracy or look at what your model actually learned.